# Param of POST method always get null value in WebAPI

Tags: c#, reactjs, webapi

[code from react](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SDAS.png)I have built a project by webApi and react. When I call a post method from react  but the parameter of the Post method in webApi  always Null.

Comment: Could you please share your code to better understand the problem and what how you tried to tackle it

Comment: export  function AddChild():JSX.Element {
    
        const { register, handleSubmit,formState:{errors} } = useForm<Child>();

        const AddChild = async (data: Child) => {
          console.log("start")
          console.log(data);
          let customerPromise = axios.post("https://localhost:44323/api/Child", data);
          let response = await customerPromise;
          console.log(response.data);
      }